# fgets not reading the beginning of a line

Tags: c, macos, file, fgets

I am having trouble reading a few lines of text from a file using fgets. The file is some basic user data that is written to a file within the bundle the first time the plugin is launched. Any subsequent launch of the plugin should result in the user data being read and cross referenced to check the users authenticity.

The data is always 3 lines long and is written with frwite exactly as it should be and is opened with fopen.

My original theory was to just call fgets 3 times reading each line into it's own char array which is part of a data struct. The problem is the first line is read correctly, the second line is read as though the position indicator starts on the next line but offset by the number of characters read from line 1. The third line is then not read at all.

fgets is not returning any errors and is behaving as though it has read the data it should have so i'm obviously missing something.

Anyway here's a portion of my code hopefully someone can some shed some light on my mistakes!

```
int length;

fgets(var.n, 128, regFile);
length = strlen(var.n);
var.n[length-1] = NULL;

fgets(var.em, 128, regFile);
length = strlen(var.em);
var.em[length-1] = NULL;

fgets(var.k, 128, regFile);
length = strlen(var.k);
var.k[length-1] = NULL;

fclose(regFile);
```

Setting the last character in each string to NULL is just to remove the /n

This sequence of code outputs the whole of line 1, the second half of line 2 and none of line 3.

Comment: did you check if that file has proper EOL chars? a dos-text file won't read the same as a unix text file or a mac text file.

Comment: Note: Under select cases, `strlen(var.n) --> 0` and `var.n[length-1] = anything` is a problem.  Recommend checking the result of `fgets()` against `NULL` and testing if the `length > 0` before doing `var.n[length-1] = '\0'`.

Comment: 1) Show the definition of `var.n`.  2) Minor, use `'\0'` as in `var.em[length-1] ='\0';` rather than `NULL`.

Comment: Are `var.n` and `var.em` of type `char *` by any chance?

Comment: @chux Minor-minor... use `= 0;` and let the compiler sort it out via conversion. Not a big deal until you're porting a mountain of code with character literals seemingly everything from `char` to `wchar_t`, at which time you either (a) wish you had, or (b) are glad you did =)

Comment: can you show the content of the file ?

Comment: @WhozCraig using `char a = 0` or `char b = '\0'` works for me - either way.  I favor the C spec style which appears to be `'\0'`.  I rate this a style issue.  But `char c = NULL` is poor as it confuses `pointer` vs `int`.

Comment: `fwrite()` is not compatible with `fgets()`. Files created using `fwrite()` should use `fread()` to read them back in. Both `fwrite()` and `fread()` operates on binary streams unless explicitly converted to and from strings. `fgets()` is compatible with `fputs()`, both operates on strings.

Comment: @MarcB Yep, the file has the correct EOL chars as i write these and they are read back in. Hence the removal of the last char in the code above.

Comment: @chux var is a struct that contains a few ints and then 3 char arrays. Namely n, em and k all declared as char n[128].

Comment: @WhozCraig Whilst you do probably have a point about the semantics used this is not what is causing the issue. These NULL chars are only stuffed on the end to remove the /n chars and this is having the desired affect. The issue existed before I added this portion of the code.

Comment: @alvits Thanks, i will give this a try. I cannot see anything in the documentation of either function to imply they would not be compatible. Especially as the file is closed and reopened between the write and read phases, at no point using a 'b' flag in the fopen call.

Comment: InfluentialAudio The issue @WhozCraig and I discussed is this code's use of `NULL`, which is a pointer - the _null pointer constant_. It has the value of 0.  Its use, rather than the `int` `0` or `int` `'\0'`, which is the C null character, implies a lack of clarity on the coder's part.  Could use `var.n[length-1] = 0.0;` and likely the same code would be generated, but `0.0` is a `double`: the right value, but wrong type.  This is the same when using `var.n[length-1] = NULL;`:  right value, wrong type.  But as you say, likely not core to this problem - just a distraction.

Comment: @chux fair enough - all my coding is self taught so I suspect i'm quite a way off when it comes to best practice. If it gets the job done (probably wrongly) i tend to ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: @InfluentialAudio - The 'b' flag is ignored on all POSIX conforming  systems, including Linux. In Linux text files and binary files are treated the same.

Comment: "ignore compiler warnings", if it gets the job done, is _OK_ if the code is then thrown away after the job is done.  The trouble is that the code may have gotten the 1st job done, but will it perform as needed for the next job with different input at a different time?  Those compiler warnings are 99.99% of the time correct indications the code is doing something potentially wrong - maybe not on the 1st job, but the next.  Suggest not accepting code with warnings - saves you and others a lot of time - in the long run.

Comment: @alvits thanks for the info again. Could you explain why the use of fputs() over fwrite() made a difference in this instance? If you want to write your suggestion as an answer i'll happy give you the credit for this one too.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer since the comment area is too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In POSIX systems, including Linux, there is no differentiation between binary and text files. When opening a file stream, the `b` flag is ignored. This is described in `fopen()`.

You might ask "how would you differentiate text from binary files?". The contents differentiate them. How the contents are written makes them a binary or text file.

Look at the signature `size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)`. You'll notice that it writes the contents of `*ptr` with `size` describing the size of each members, `nmemb`. The written stream is not converted to string. If you were to write 97 it will write the binary 97 which in ascii is `A`. Binary data does not obey string terminations. Presence of `\n` and `\0` in data is literally written as is.

Now look at the signature `int fputs(const char *s, FILE *stream)`. It writes the string content of `*s`. If you were to write 97, it will have to be a string "97" which is not `A`. String termination is obeyed. `\n` is automatically converted to the O/S supported newline (CRLF or LF).

You can coerce `fwrite()` to behave like `fputs()` but not the other way around. For example, if you declare `ptr` as a pointer to string and calculate the size exactly as the length of the content excluding string terminator, you'll be able to write it out as text instead of binary. You will also need to handle `\0` and `\n` and convert them to O/S supported newline. Writing the entire string buffer will write everything including and past the string terminators.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, this is very helpful. I know exactly what is going on now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @alvits for the answer to this one:

> fwrite() is not compatible with fgets(). Files created using fwrite() should use fread() to read them ?>back in. Both fwrite() and fread() operates on binary streams unless explicitly converted to and from >strings. fgets() is compatible with fputs(), both operates on strings.

I used fputs() to write my data instead and it read back in perfectly.

Comment: `fwrite()` and `fgets()` can be compatible.  It depends on how code uses them.  Since the question did not post how code was written, determining why there was an incompatibility between data written and read is a challenge.

Comment: "Both `fwrite()` and `fread()` operates on streams: binary _and_ text.  If they are operating on binary or text streams depends on the mode that the stream/file was opened, not on what functions, `fwrite()`, `fgets()` use them.  Certainly functions like `fwrite()` are better suited for binary streams and `fgets()` with text streams, but they are not limited to those stream modes.

Comment: @chux I did mention in my original question that i used frwite() but as i also mentioned in my comment to alvits above i couldn't see any logical reason myself why they wouldn't be compatible. I have not specified a 'b' flag in the call to fopen() so the files should be opened as 'text' by default. All this aside what alvits suggested has solved the issue and all i did was replace my fwrite() calls with fputs() so there must be some truth to it.

Comment: The post does not show how `fwrite()` was used.  Mentioning that code use `fwrite()` is incomplete.  Since the problem was one of not properly reading well what was written, it makes sense to have posted not only the code than does the reading, but also the code that does the writing.  @alvits suggestion may mend the issue for you and that is good.  It still appears you still do not know why things failed.  If using a tool fails, it does not prove the tool is wrong, maybe how the tool was used is the issue?